# Windows 8.1 store xaml save InkManager in a string

Tags: image, xaml, windows-store-apps, drawing, windows-8.1

I'm trying to save what i have drawn with the pencil as a string , and i do this by SaveAsync() method to put it in an  IOutputStream then convert this IOutputStream to a stream using AsStreamForWrite() method from this point things should go fine, however i get a lot of problems after this part , if i use for example this code block:

```
  using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[2048]; // read in chunks of 2KB
                   int bytesRead = (int)size;
                    while (bytesRead < 0)
                    {
                        stream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);

                    }
                    byte[] result = stream.ToArray();
                    // TODO: do something with the result
                }
```

i get this exception

```
"Offset and length were out of bounds for the array or count is greater than the number of elements from index to the end of the source collection."
```

or if i try to convert the stream into an image using InMemoryRandomAccessStream like this:

```
 InMemoryRandomAccessStream ras = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();
                await s.CopyToAsync(ras.AsStreamForWrite());
```

my InMemoryRandomAccessStream variable is always zero in size.

also tried

```
StreamReader.ReadToEnd();
```

but it returns an empty string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the answer here :

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/2359f360-832e-4ce5-8315-7f351f2edf6e/stream-inkmanager-strokes-to-string

```
private async void ReadInk(string  base64)
{
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(base64))
{
    var bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64);

    using (var inMemoryRAS = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream())
    {
        await inMemoryRAS.WriteAsync(bytes.AsBuffer());
        await inMemoryRAS.FlushAsync();
        inMemoryRAS.Seek(0);

        await m_InkManager.LoadAsync(inMemoryRAS);

        if (m_InkManager.GetStrokes().Count > 0)
        {
            // You would do whatever you want with the strokes
            // RenderStrokes(); 
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Have you implemented the `WriteInk()` method from the link above? If yes what's the signature of the method calling `WriteInk()`? `WriteInk()` is failing after `await m_InkCanvas.SaveAsync(stream);` and a Catastophic Failure is being thrown when calling `WriteInk()'. Any idea how to solve it? Here's my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30751449/save-taskstring-type-to-string-giving-catastrophic-failure