# Save Task<string> type to String giving Catastrophic failure

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, base64, async-await, windows-8.1

I am trying to save the Ink I write on Canvas in a class and reload it with these two methods found at this [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/2359f360-832e-4ce5-8315-7f351f2edf6e/stream-inkmanager-strokes-to-string?forum=winappswithcsharp).

```
    private async Task<string> WriteInk() {
        using (var stream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream()) {
            await inkManager.SaveAsync(stream);
            await stream.FlushAsync();
            stream.Seek(0);
            byte[] bytes = new byte[stream.Size];
            IBuffer buffer = bytes.AsBuffer();
            await stream.ReadAsync(buffer, (uint)stream.Size, InputStreamOptions.None);
            return Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
        }
    }

    private async void ReadInk(string base64) {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(base64)) return;
        var bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64);

        using (var stream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream()) {
            await stream.WriteAsync(bytes.AsBuffer());
            await stream.FlushAsync();
            stream.Seek(0);

            await inkManager.LoadAsync(stream);

            if (inkManager.GetStrokes().Count > 0) {
                RenderInk();
            }
        }
    }
```

I have a class where I save the base64 returned from `WriteInk()`:

```
    public class MyCanvas
    {
        public string canvasIndex { get; set; }
        public String canvasStrokes { get; set; }
    }
```

My problem is when calling `WriteInk()`:

```
MyCanvas mc = new MyCanvas();
mc.canvasStrokes = await m_CanvasManager1.WriteInk();
```

I get an Exception: Catastrophic failure.
+ I can't make `canvasStrokes` of type `string` and save `Task<string>` to it
+ The method `ReadInk()` takes the base64 as a `string`

To what type should I save `Task<string>` to be able to use it as `string` in the second method?

When I call WriteInk, it arrives to `await inkCanvas.SaveAsync(stream);`
it returns to where it was called at `mc.canvasStrokes = await m_CanvasManager0.WriteInk();`and give this exception:

`An exception of type 'System.Exception' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code. Additional information: Catastrophic failure (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8000FFFF (E_UNEXPECTED))`

Comment: Does it work fine if you do a non-async `WriteInk` that returns `string` and calls the non-async versions instead of awaiting on the async versions?

Comment: How can `WriteInk` **not** be asynchronous when I have `m_InkManager.SaveAsync(stream);`?

Comment: By using `Save` if it has one, otherwise by calling `Wait()` on it if it doesn't. If you make a non asynchronous version then whether the bug is only in one version, or is in both, will help figure out the bug. (This is also somewhere where the convention of ending task-returning methods with `Async` helps, as then you can have both coëxisting).

Comment: `InkManager` only has a `SaveAsync()` method, and `Wait()` doesn't exist in Windows Store Apps. A non asynchronous method might be impossible?

Comment: Ah, sorry. Of course it doesn't.

Comment: Please post the complete exception with stack trace.

Comment: I just added them in my updated question up here!

Comment: ¿What is the Message of the Exception?